# Place icons on second monitor

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

I have a dual screen setup which works fine, but I cannot put desktop icons on the second monitor. My left screen is configured to be the main screen, but it doesn't really matter, even if I configure the right screen to be the main screen I cannot place any icons there. They always go back to their original location on the left monitor. I can move and place the icons on the left monitor wherever I want, but once I try to move them to the other screen they move back to the left screen. Is there any way to change that?

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3gKlDgR05s) wasn't made by me, but it shows the same behaviour as I am experiencing, so if my explanation wasn't good enough, have a look.

Comment: Icons can be placed anywhere on a dual monitor set-up with Linux Mint 17.x (Cinnamon). I'm guessing it would be possible on 18.x too. Must be something to do with xfce.

Comment: @Tigger: Yeah, I installed Mate just to test it (didn't like it for other reasons) and there it was no problem placing monitors on the other screen.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the second monitor, Desktop Settings.

Choose the option "Show desktop icons on all monitors"

[image]

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long to get back to you. Unfortunatly I don't have that option in the desktop settings. I'm using xfce 4.12.1 btw.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. I replaced my older Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2 and went to 18.3 and this got me confused. Thank you!